# using one controllers actions within another controllers views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I use another controllers methods inside of another controllers views?

I have a Users controller and a Worlds controller each with their own model and views. I am trying to use something from the Worlds view within the Users views

```
<% @worlds.each do |world| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

but I am getting
"You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each"

this listing of each world works as expected when used within the Worlds views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define in your action in UsersController your `@worlds` variabe:

```
# UsersController
def index
  @worlds = World.all
end
```

And you should understand, that Models and Controllers are different essences. The are separated. Controller can use **any** model. Controller is a layer between all models and particular view.

Comment: That would still return a Nil object. The UsersController has no access to any of my WorldsController's data.

Comment: What are you talking about? You NEVER NEED to have acces to ANY of data in another controller. You need to fetch it from DATABASE through your MODELS. This is so basic knowledge of MVC so I even don't know if there are any tutorials about this :D

Comment: show your UsersController and WorldsController and explain which data you want to share

Comment: http://pastebin.com/a9eLwDSd - WorldsController
http://pastebin.com/wsbF6VG5 - UsersController.

Just trying to list all worlds associated with a user when you go to their profile. I got an idea how to do all that. my issue is just accessing the info from within a Users/View

Comment: just fetch in your particluar action in UsersController: `@worlds = current_user.worlds`

Comment: Also: there is no any profile or show action in your UsersController.

Comment: Thanks! The info you provided helped me solve my issue and it taught me something. The profile action is just the Edit action.